Instantiating TypeSense client using api key from GCP Secret Manager
I'm new to GCP and only little exposure on node.js. But looking at some documentation, tutorials and samples I saw in the internet, I am now able to invoke the cloud function, instantiate the typesense client, do the search and return the result. However, the api key "my-api-key" is hardcoded in the typesense client initialization.
My next step is to have the api key retrieved from the secret manager. I was able to set it up and the code in the secretclient.js is working, at least if invoked separately.
I've been trying to set the apiKey from secret manager without success. The accessSecretVersion is async and seems to be not meant to be used in this kind of initializations. What is the best solution in this case?
[index.js]
const {tsClient} = require("./typesense");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.someProcess = onRequest (async (request, response) => {
    <!-- code to construct searchParam -->
    const result = await tsClient.multiSearch.perform(searchParam);
    logger.info(result);

    <!-- process the result and save to another collection -->
    response.send(result); // for testing
});

[typesense.js]
const Typesense = require("typesense");

const client = new Typesense.Client({
  nodes: [{
    host: "typesense.host.com",
    port: "443",
    protocol: "https",
  }],
  apiKey: "my-api-key",
  connectionTimeoutSeconds: 5,
});

exports.tsClient = client;

[secretclient.js]
const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require("@google-cloud/secret-manager");
const secretClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

module.exports = ( async () => {
  const [version] = await secretClient.accessSecretVersion({
    name: "projects/projectid/secrets/TYPESENSE_API_KEY/versions/latest",
  });
  const searchApiKey = version.payload.data.toString();
  console.log("search api key : " + searchApiKey);
  return searchApiKey;
})();

What I have tried so far:

calling await secretclient from typesense initialization. NOT WORKING. because calling function is not async
top level await: getting different kinds of errors, runtime, eslint, or the typesense client not setting the apikey.

Can someone point me to the right direction. TIA
BTW, I was trying this top level await to make the typesense client global, is that a good approach so as not to constantly reading secret manager and instantiating everytime the cloud function is invoked?
